# Loop nested System.object[] C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I've a variable of type Object and it contains data like this

> Items[0]=[ {id=a,name=b,url=c},{id=d,name=e,url=f},{id=a,name=b,url=c}...]
>
> Items[1]=[ {id=a,name=b,url=c},{id=d,name=e,url=f},{id=a,name=b,url=c}...]
>
> .....

how can I loop this?

***UPDATE***

```
            if (null != myProjects) //myProjectsis of type object
            {
                dirEntry = myProjects as Dictionary<string, object>;
                dirDetails = dirEntry["Response"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                object projects = null;
                foreach (var item in dirDetails)
                {
                    if ("Items" == item.Key)
                    {
                        projects = dirDetails["Items"];
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

now `projects`  will contain object array.
I wan't to loop that to get some values

Comment: what is the type of embedded data? Is it just another array/collection?

Comment: Nested ForEach should do your job for you. But what kind of operation you want to do within the loop? If it is something achievable by LINQ depends on what you want to do within the loop

Comment: what is the `typeof` Items?

Comment: @evhen14 yes.. another array

Comment: @Mujahid Daud Khan strings

Comment: you want to parse data from collection of Strings?

Comment: @ Mujahid Daud Khan  yeah.. but I'm not able to use foreach on this. also objname["index"] also not allowed.. :(

Comment: are you trying to modify data in loop? update your question with the code that you have tried.

Comment: You want to loop through items (item[0], item[1], etc... ) or just loop through item[0...n] individually?

Comment: Try `if(dirDetails.ContainsKey("Items")) projects = dirDetails["Items"] `

Comment: @Sudheesh in projects is array boxing to object or something else?

Comment: @ Mujahid Daud Khan same result\

Comment: your question is I wan't to loop that to get some values? which values, i mean your question is not clear, if your have the value at a particular index than what is the need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow this sample,

**Class for project data(id, name, url)**

```
public class ObjectList
{
    public ObjectList(string id1, string name1, string url1)
    {
        id = id1;
        name = name1;
        url = url1;
    }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

**Class for array items(projects)**

```
 public class RootObj
    {
        public string objectType { get; set; }
        public List<ObjectList> objectList { get; set; }
    }
```

Once you have got the object based array, here is the sample you can follow to loop through the projects.

```
private void ManipulateProjects()
{
    object[] projects = new object[5];

    RootObj item1Obj = new RootObj();
    List<ObjectList> item1List = new List<ObjectList>();
    item1List.Add(new ObjectList("1", "Rone1", "htt://google1.com"));
    item1List.Add(new ObjectList("2", "Rone2", "htt://google2.com"));
    item1List.Add(new ObjectList("3", "Rone3", "htt://google3.com"));
    item1Obj.objectList = item1List;
    projects[0] = item1Obj;

    RootObj item2Obj = new RootObj();
    List<ObjectList> item2List = new List<ObjectList>();
    item2List.Add(new ObjectList("10", "Rone10", "htt://google10.com"));
    item2List.Add(new ObjectList("12", "Rone12", "htt://google20.com"));
    item2List.Add(new ObjectList("13", "Rone13", "htt://google30.com"));
    item2Obj.objectList = item2List;
    projects[1] = item2Obj;

    //Once you have your formatted array of projects then it is just a matter of looping through it.
    foreach (RootObj item in projects)
    {
        if (item == null) continue;
        List<ObjectList> items = item.objectList;

        foreach (ObjectList item1 in items)
        {
            //Response.Write(item1.id + " " + item1.name + " " + item1.url + "<br />");
        }
    }
}
```